# CInema 4D Sudden Loss of All Textures in Render

Tags: texture, cinema4d

So i am having a strange problem.  I have a scene I am working on that is 1020 frames long.  For most of it, the camera is at a -3 degree angle as we swosh down was looks like a tron grid.  Near the end, it pans up as a logo comes out of the floor.  Up to and through frame 883 everything renders fine (hadn't added lighting just using default illumination).  Then on frame 884, no textures render without dropping a light of 1000% intensity and even then they just barely show.  The camera has panned up to an angle of 0.215 degrees on P.  And from there out as it pans up to a 15 degree angle it remains this way.  Now adding the light is fine but the problem is that the scene up to and through 883 now are all over-saturated with light and everything looks horrible.  So I am at a loss of what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is (without seeing an image) probably because specular highlights (light reflecting off the surface) are obscuring the textures. Your placing of the higher powered single light source might be overcoming this specularity from a larger light that's tangential to the camera/surface relationships when the textures "disappear".